# Issue in validate phone number using javascript in php register form

Tags: javascript, php

Here is my code for validating phone number;

```
  if(!(preg_match([0-9]{10})|(\([0-9]{3}\)\s+[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}, $_POST['phone'])))
        die(msg(0,"You haven't provided a valid phone number"));
```

After enter all the input details, it shows like loading.

Can anyone say what is the mistake in my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: If it shows a loading icon, I bet you are using ajax to submit your form. Open the developer tool in your browser, and see what the script you are posting to are returning. It should be generating an error

Comment: yes, i am using ajax.. ok. how do i know developer tool.  i am using firefox

Comment: Either use Firebug or the buildin activated by F12

Comment: this is the link when i press F12 http://s29.postimg.org/ba1n77u47/Untitled_1_copy.png. there is no error occured

Comment: Have a look at the console. It should show the ajax query, and the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
if(!(preg_match("/([0-9]{10})|([0-9]{3}\\s+[0-9]{3}\\s+[0-9]{4})/", $_POST['phone'])))
die(msg(0,"You haven't provided a valid phone number"));
```

Mainly, there were two problems with your regex.

First: You had forgot to put your regular expression inside quotes. 
Second: After the opening quote, and before the closing quote, you should have /

This building the pregmatch like: preg_match("/regex/", $string);

And finally, the regular expression itself contained some errors.

I recommend using this tool if you are new to regex:

http://regex101.com/

**Second part:**

The reason you are having issues with your form showing loading is because the PHP-script which it is posting data to, is throwing an error. This error needs to be fetched by the ajax script and returned to the browser. Simply using die('a message'); will kill the script and return "a message" to the query. You need to add a function to handle any error responses.

Use a browser developer tool like FireBug or any buil in tool in your browser to have a look at the output of your ajax query:

[image]

A good way to do a ajax call would be like:

```
var formData = $('#yourform').serialize();
$.ajax({
    url : "/link_to_script.php",
    type : "POST",
    data: formData,
    dataType: "json",
    success : function(d){
        if( d.success) {
            // An array key called success is located with the value of true
            alert( 'Successfully submitted form' );
        }
        if( d.error ){
            // An array key called error is located with the value of true
            alert( d.errormsg );
            // Alerts the visitor with the content of the return array key "errormsg"
        }
    },
    error: function(){
        alert( 'Something went wrong' );
        // This error function will be returned if the data returned by script is not json, or if the script cannot be reached / returns any kind of 404/500 error or such.
    }
});
```

This will handle a json output from your PHP script and interperate its data. If the call is successfull, it should contain some data from your PHP script, like for example a success message or an error message. This needs to be return like for example this:

```
<?php
    echo json_encode( array( 'success'=> true, 'message' => 'Uploaded file' ) );
    // OR, incase error like the preg_match:
    echo json_encode( array( 'error' => true, 'errormsg' => 'Phone not validated' ) );
```

This will json encode an array with the data you want to handle with your ajax script.

Comment: What does it say exactly. Please use a developer tool, have a look at the consol in it as you submit the form, and reply with the content of the result.

Comment: See, in your developer tool, there is a button called "console". Click that. Then submit your form. There you should see the result of the post just like in the pictures I added in my answer

Comment: Include the html and javascript from your form page to your question please

Comment: Nothing wrong with that part. How does your submit.php look?

Comment: What is the content of your submit.php file

Comment: Hard to say without the the whole thing. Either, you have an error in your php functions causing an fatal error while executing the script, or you have a javascript error causing the ajax call not to be made at all. If you could make a zip of your project and upload, Ill try and run it locally. But play around with the developer tool. An error should be thrown there somewhere

Comment: It works fine with me. So the problem is locally at your server

Comment: When you only fill out half of the form and press submit, do you get the error message under the submit button?

Comment: No clue. As I said, local problem. Either your browser is so old it doesnt recognize ajax, doesnt support it, or just aint firing the javascript because of some other problem. Further than this, is beyond me

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to validate mobile no in browser.

```
<input name="mobilenum" pattern="[789][0-9]{9}" placeholder="Contact Number" required="" type="text">
```

Comment: Not supported by all browser though. Safari doesnt recognize it, and neither earlier versions of IE.